# Query based on cell reference on multiple conditions on Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I am trying to create a search function where users are able to select from a list in Google Sheets and the below query function will return that data that corresponds from the users' selections.

```
=query(Overview!A:AF,"SELECT D,I,M,AA WHERE AA = '"B27"' AND L ">=" "&E27&" AND S CONTAINS '"&H27&"'",1)
```

I expected to get the list (D, I, M, AA) but I keep getting `#ERROR`, what is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

this is the correct syntax:

```
=QUERY(Overview!A:AF; "SELECT D,I,M,AA 
                       WHERE AA = '"&B27&"' 
                         AND L >= '"&E27&"'
                         AND S CONTAINS '"&H27&"'"; 1)
```